# Can you extend an introductory (0%) credit card offer?

Tags: credit-card, interest-rate, negotiation

Most of us have heard those stories about how cable companies, if pressured over the phone and threatened with a customer's cancellation of service, will offer up special deals / offers to retain the customer.

In short, I'm interested in knowing if one could achieve similar results with a credit card offer.

I have a credit card that gave me 18 months of 0% interest. There are no other significant benefits of the card.

My question is: **Is it likely that if I threaten to close the card, they'll extend this intro period, if I ask?**

I don't currently carry a balance, but like the option of doing so at no interest if anything comes up. This is the only thing that actually motivates me to keep the card open.

So I'm interested to know **whether anyone has succeeded or tried this before (?), and what their results / experiences were.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it likely that if I threaten to close the card, they'll extend this
>   intro period, if I ask?

No. It's very unlikely. Never hurts to ask, but I'm guessing you'll be put on hold while they go laugh for a couple of minutes.

Now, if you are a loyal customer that has a good history of on-time payments and are considered low-risk for the bank, then they might make you an offer like quid refers to in his answer. This scenario is actually quite common and can be recommended. Calling a bank that you've been using for several years and letting them know you can get a better option elsewhere may prompt them to lower your base interest rate (especially if your credit score has increased since your line was initially established), offer another promotional period, or maybe offer to switch you to a card with better benefits.

0% interest rate offers are there to get you hooked to using their card. They're banking (pun sort of intended) on you getting to the end of that 18 month period with a balance and then charging you 18%+ interest on it. That's how they make their money off of you. What possible motivation would they have to want to keep you at 0%? They'd rather have you go to another bank, frankly.

If your interest rate after the promo period is on the higher end, then I'd definitely call after the promo period and see if they can drop that. It's not uncommon to have rates dropped to 9% (or less) if you're creditworthiness is there and they see you as a good potential customer.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of a credit card issuer extending out an expiring 0% introductory rate for new purchases.  However, when I was younger and wanted to make a big purchase I knew I couldn't pay immediately I called my three cards to see if any would do anything.  One offered me 2.9% on any charges made that month.  Alternatively, another offered to lower my interest rate a couple percent, which I took; and the other offered nothing.

Obviously your mileage may vary but it's worth asking.

Comment: ^ I removed my initial comment here as I'd misread your answer as never hearing of someone 'offering' 0%, when I re-read and saw 'extending' I removed my comment

Comment: I've also never seen it extended, but I constantly get offers in the mail from my existing cards to do 0% balance transfers for X number of months. You need to watch the balance transfer fee, but there are plenty of people out there (opinions about if they should or not aside) that move balances back and forth between multiple cards to keep taking advantage of those types of offers.

Comment: @BobbyScon I don't have much of a balance right now, but am interested in having the card around in case anything happens in which I have to start making charges that I can't pay off immediately (such as loss of a job, medical issues causing sudden payments, etc). So If I did use the card, I'd more or less suddenly start racking up charges and leaving them sit with no interest

Comment: @schizoid04 - I understand what you're interested in, I was really just stating that I've also never heard of a bank offering this before. You're costing the bank money by having an account that doesn't yield them any interest. Why would they want to extend no interest on new purchases to keep you?